# Ridge and Lasso Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I understand how these algorithms works but there is one thing which i don't got it. Ridge and Lasso regressions apply penalty to independent variable's coefficient. I understand it. But How is this happening. How apply penalty to coefficient?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In ordinary least squares, ones solves a minimization problem for the unknown coefficients of the independent variables. In ridge or lasso regression, this optimization problem is modified and the solution method is also modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good resource is [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html). To answer your question

As with all ML models you are trying to minimise/maximise an objective function,
$$
L_{\text{ridge}}= ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||^2_2
$$
and
$$
L_{\text{lasso}} = \frac{1}{2 * n_{\text{samples}}} * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||_1
$$
you can generally write these as
$$
L = ||y - Xw||^2_2 + \text{Penalty}
$$
and it is the penalty that restricts the coefficients.

If you are asking why do it like this, this is a way to deal with large coefficients (corresponding to overindexing on a particular features) it helps with generalising and not relying too much on the data.

You can also look into the bayesian approach to getting to ridge/lasso [here](https://ekamperi.github.io/mathematics/2020/08/02/bayesian-connection-to-lasso-and-ridge-regression.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's pretty helpfully.

Comment: @EmirKutsal if this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left.